# Fragment slow loading due to large layout

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment

There is a navigation view and click on a specific item takes a bit of time to load. I believe it's due to the size of the layout. The layout is of a long form. I there any way I can avoid the lag?

Below is the layout

https://pastebin.pl/view/0cfa5f9c

Tried dividing the form into two but still same issue even with reduced views. I feel like the lag started with the first TextInputLayout view.

Comment: this is not with the views there is something else you are trying to do on the main thread. if not, check if the data being fetched & showed on UI are done in the background thread using coroutines also check if there are two fragments simultaneously loaded for example in the view pager it is possible that two fragments can be loaded simultaneously.

Comment: I haven't written any backend code. It's just the layout. Also, no fragments are loaded simultaneously as well. The lag increases with the number of views.

Comment: You have to load the views dynamically when the user scrolls. There are messengers which show 1000s of messages. The views for these messages are created dynamically when the user scrolls. You have to replace your ScrollView by RecyclerView but I'm not 100% sure. Search for "Android endless scrolling".

Comment: I have used recycler view to load data through API but how to do it with views? The order of the views is not the same. There are radio buttons, auto complete textviews, edittexts etc.

Comment: @AbhinandAK Phan if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems and you just have your layout, try removing your Linear Layouts and make a flat layout using only Constraint Layout. [Nested layout](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies#managing) can impose layout cost.

Comment: Still same ...https://pastebin.pl/view/b09b6af0